# Specify different (basic) authentication log-in per endpoint Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Imagine the following (hypothetical) data structure

```
endpoint | username | password
users      admin      123
info       george     awd
data       magnus     e4
```

this means that every endpoint requires different credentials and no one username/password combo can log in to every endpoint. I am looking for a way to make this scalable in our Spring MVC project when adding more endpoints. We could use roles and hardcore this into the config class but the endpoints and login combinations vary for every customer installation

Given the following SecurityConfiguration with LookupAuthenticationService being the class that looks up the username/password data in the database

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] ENDPOINT_LIST = {
        "/rest/**"
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(ENDPOINT_LIST)
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new LookupAuthenticationService(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

The ideal situation would be if LookupAuthenticationService has access to the request so we know which endpoint to fetch but I guess this is only possible when working with individual Filters

The possibilities I've found so far are:

- Add a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and multiple UserDetailsServer specific per endpoint -> lots of code
- Add a HandlerInterceptor per endpoint -> lots of code
- AuthenticationManagerResolver returning a different AuthenticationManager based on pathInfo?

Any input how to best resolve this issue would be appreciated

Comment: endpoint is just an authority, just add rules, for the url mapping and the authority. 1 config solved.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this @M.Deinum?

Comment: You can write a user query which maps the `endpoint` column to the authority/roles of a user. You can then just add security for urls/endpoints for a given authority.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a table where you map endpoints to rules, like so:

| pattern | authority |
| --- | --- |
| /users/** | ROLE_ADMIN |
| /info/** | ROLE_USER |
| /another/** | ROLE_ANOTHER |

And instead of assigning a user to an endpoint, you assign a role to the users. With this in place, you can create an `AuthorizationManager` which is going to protect your endpoints based on the request path.

```java
@Component
public class AccessRuleAuthorizationManager implements AuthorizationManager<RequestAuthorizationContext> {

    private final AccessRuleRepository rules;
    private RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager delegate;

    public AccessRuleAuthorizationManager(AccessRuleRepository rules) {
        this.rules = rules;
    }

    @Override
    public AuthorizationDecision check(Supplier<Authentication> authentication, RequestAuthorizationContext object) {
        return this.delegate.check(authentication, object.getRequest());
    }

    @EventListener
    void applyRules(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        Builder builder = builder();
        for (AccessRule rule : this.rules.findAll()) {
            builder.add(
                    new AntPathRequestMatcher(rule.getPattern()),
                    AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasAuthority(rule.getAuthority())
            );
        }
        this.delegate = builder.build();
    }
}
```

And, in your `SecurityConfiguration` you simply do this:

```java
@Autowired
private AccessRuleAuthorizationManager access;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> 
                authz.anyRequest().access(this.access)
           )
           .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
}
```

I recommend you to take a look at [this repository](https://github.com/sjohnr/springone-2021) and watch the presentation from the repository's description. The last steps of the presentation was adding the custom `AuthorizationManager`, and there's a great explanation about it.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive reply, it helped me gain insight as to what I actually wanted to ask. I will probably delete this question as it does not make a lot of sense.

Unfortunately in our system users are not traditional users and multiple users can be defined with the same username but with different passwords - not allowing me to set roles for an individual user. I'm in need of a more on-the-fly way of handling things which UserDetailsService/loadUserByUsername does not allow